# Get all records that don't exist in a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to return all records that are not in the subquery (of which there should be a lot) but I get no results.

I want all of the records where the `LastAccesstime` (datetime) doesn't have an access time which is within 24hours of `GETDATE()`. Does that make sense? I tried `WHERE NOT IN` as well and got the same results.

```
SELECT Firstname, Surname, LastAccesstime 
from Users
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT Firstname, Surname, LastAccesstime from Users 
WHERE (LastAccesstime) >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
AND (LastAccesstime) < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE())+1, 0)
)
```

The table consists of many other fields including a UserID but this isn't important for my question as once I'm able to return the correct result set I should be able to do what I need to do.

Thanks

Comment: can you just do `where datediff(hour,lastaccesstime,getdate()) > 24`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Richard's answer is definitely on the right track.  However, `datediff()` is not the right function to use.  It counts the number of *boundaries* between two date/time values.  So, "2016-01-01 23:59" and "2016-01-02 00:01" are one day apart (because of the midnight boundary).

In SQL Server, it is better to use direct comparisons on the dates:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE u.lastaccesstime < DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE());
```

This also has the advantage that it can take advantage of an index on `lastaccesstime`.

Note:

Your query suggests that you don't want to include the time component for `GETDATE()`.  If so, just cast to a `date` data type:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE u.lastaccesstime < DATEADD(day, -1, CAST(GETDATE() as DATE));
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that lastaccesstime is always in the past then

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE DATEDIFF(HOUR, ISNULL(lastaccesstime, GETDATE() - 2), GETDATE()) > 24
```

Comment: That should work. I dont know why I made it so complicated. THank you :)